# Decrypt the data converted from RSA Encryption?

Tags: iphone

I have tried iPhone encryption using below post, But i dont know how to decrypt from encrypted data using RSA Encryption. Please direct me and send me sample code if possible. 
Also is it possible decrypt the data in server side like PHP, JAVA and .NET?

[RSA Encryption-Decryption in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788569/rsa-encryption-decryption-in-iphone)

Sri

Comment: What RSA code? I see a base64 encoding algorithm, not an RSA encryption algorithm.

Comment: If you use RSA encryption, you just need the private key. It should not matter on which platform, language you decrypt a message. Btw. the accepted answer of the question you refer to just generates a hash, it does not encrypt.

Answer (score 1):

For iphone Check out the CommonCrypto API, the Security framework API and the CryptoExercise sample code http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html

In java you have java.security.interfaces.RSAKey java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey
 etc

In php you have the http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_RSA/ PEAR package

Answer (score 1):

For PHP, check out Crypt_RSA in http://phpseclib.sourceforge.org .  The problem with PEAR's Crypt_RSA is that it doesn't really conform to any published standard:

http:/pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16870

http:/pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=7257