# Using Touch ID for multiple user

Tags: objective-c, ios9, fingerprint

I am still studying for touch ID api.

I know that touch ID will just return yes or no only when user unlock in app.

I copy some code from here.

[Generate key pair on iphone and print to log as NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064710/generate-key-pair-on-iphone-and-print-to-log-as-nsstring)

```
OSStatus status = noErr;
NSMutableDictionary *privateKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *publicKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *keyPairAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//.....................
```

Is it possible to use touch ID to differentiate multiple user?

In iOS 9, we can encrypt key with finger print. Private key will be stored in device and app can use public key.

Can I use that for multiple user? I just want to differentiate multiple username and password based on particular finger print.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't differentiate between different fingerprints on the same device. Touch ID expects that all fingerprints are for the same user, or at least they all authenticate for the same purposes.

Further reading: https://support.apple.com/HT204587