# Convert NSData object to NSString format

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I am getting something like this in NSData and I want to print it as NSString Data, So can I get some solutions for this.

My data is

> (<30820605 308204ed a0030201 02021011 b5aff6d9 6c725e0d 33105e6c
>   6115a930 0d06092a 864886f7 0d01010b 05003044 310b3009 06035504
>   06130255 53311630 14060355 040a130d 47656f54 72757374 20496e63
>   2e311d30 1b060355 04031314 47656f54 72757374 2053534c 20434120
>   2d204733 301e170d 31363032 30333030 30303030 5a170d31 37303230
>   32323335 3935395a 30818431 0b300906 03550406 1302494e 3110300e
>   06035504 08130748 61727961 6e613110 300e0603 55040714 07477572
>   67616f6e 31243022 06035504 0a141b50 726f7469 6e757320 496e666f
>   74656368 20507674 2e204c74 642e3115 30130603 55040b14 0c50726f
>   64756374 20546561 6d311430 12060355 0403140b 2a2e7472 75706179
>   2e696e30 82012230 0d06092a 864886f7 0d010101 05000382 010f0030
>   82010a02 82010100 b561a9fa 80f7e7f7 c9e64b02 05259a84 c73682d6
>   b3feee24 cbf04511 18667669 52f62331 a1056106 595b22fb db63cc4b
>   c700e90f 0a1d24cb ea8f253c 3d7c8a57 5abd8f86 62c4e866 bbd0ace9
>   2c2eef5a 30046e48 a83d374b ef8f8170 cfa703d3 0099ff45 559031f8
>   53e8a67d af6552c2 4ff628c3 9979e3e0 62a5cc9a d73cb5fa a3ef6a45 )

This same data I want in string format.

I am using this piece of code

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[remoteCertificateData bytes]];
```

But I am getting nil for `myString`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTF-8 encoded NSData to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring)

Comment: So you want string from nsdata?

Comment: Why you want to convert in string for comparision ?

Comment: Format your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If the data is null-terminated, you should instead use

```
NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[theData bytes]];
```

If NSData is not UTF-8-encoded, you will get nil.

for further reference see these links:

please have look on this.

[NSData bytes to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692429/nsdata-bytes-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to match `string`. Just convert the string in `NSData` like:

```
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then compare NSData.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Code Snippet to convert NSData into NSString :

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:aNSData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```