# Parsing NSData by byte count

Tags: objective-c, hex, nsdata

I have NSData and i would like to parse it by bytes. Here is an example. 
`data is <8283010c ec4f483f 0d00000c 0c0f2840 >`

I would like to pass 8 bytes to each object i create `(8283010c ec4f483f for first object,0d00000c 0c0f2840 for the second)` , and then parse those each bytes like this.

```
  //  First byte > Action = 82
  //  2nd and 3rd byte > Status = 83 01
  //  4,5,6,7 byte > Time = 0c ec 4f48
  //  8 byte > Number = 3f
```

How could i parse NSData to such structure, what types should i use for my variables (Action)?

```
unsigned char aBuffer[8];
[data getBytes:aBuffer length:8];
```

Tried to do a little test in such way, but NSLog prints aBuffer with strange symbols, instead of byte values.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "parsing"? In this context, it doesn't quite make sense. Why don't you just copy 8 bytes from `[data bytes] + offset * 8` anyway?

Comment: What encoding does the data use? It may be returning 4 unichar characters instead of 8 ASCII characters.You should also tell us the definition of the structure, the one you provided isn't clear.

Comment: There is no encoding for data. It's raw data. It would be great if i could convert this data to like NSString somehow. H2CO3 could you write a simple example on how to do this, or point me where could i learn this. Because currently this is a dark forest to me with no light.

Comment: @Datenshi Have you ever used `printf()`? If not, have you tried reading and understanding the documentation of `NSData`? I don't think so...

Comment: Yes I'v tried both, your comment makes me feel kinda stupid. Your answer did help me, and that was exactly what i was asking for, thank you for your time. And sorry for not being smart enough to grasp everything without help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NSLog prints aBuffer with strange symbols, instead of byte values.

Because those are the **actual bytes** NSData contains, and not their hexadecimal representation. If you want a hexadecimal representation, you have to format the bytes accordingly:

```
NSMutableString *hexRepr = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    [hexRepr appendFormat:@"%02x", ((uint8_t *)[data bytes])[offset * 8 + i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up on @H2CO3's answer,

According to [NSData docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `[data description]` returns  hexadecimal representation. Wouldn't that be easier?

UPDATE: Found why `[data description]` shouldn't be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084784/58505