# Shared Memory for transfering Data (NSData) in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdata, shared-memory

Following codes demonstrate shared memory between two process (server & client )
This code transfer characters between two program , but i want to transfer NSData between two programs within this code
How can I do this?

```
     shm_server.c

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHMSZ     27

int main()
{
    char c;
    int shmid;
    key_t key;
    char *shm, *s;

    /*
     * We'll name our shared memory segment
     * "5678".
     */
    key = 5678;

    /*
     * Create the segment.
     */
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Now we attach the segment to our data space.
     */
    if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Now put some things into the memory for the
     * other process to read.
     */
    s = shm;

    for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
        *s++ = c;
    *s = NULL;

    /*
     * Finally, we wait until the other process 
     * changes the first character of our memory
     * to '*', indicating that it has read what 
     * we put there.
     */
    while (*shm != '*')
        sleep(1);

    exit(0);
}

shm_client.c

/*
 * shm-client - client program to demonstrate shared memory.
 */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHMSZ     27

int main()
{
    int shmid;
    key_t key;
    char *shm, *s;

    /*
     * We need to get the segment named
     * "5678", created by the server.
     */
    key = 5678;

    /*
     * Locate the segment.
     */
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, 0666)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Now we attach the segment to our data space.
     */
    if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Now read what the server put in the memory.
     */
    for (s = shm; *s != NULL; s++)
        putchar(*s);
    putchar('\n');

    /*
     * Finally, change the first character of the 
     * segment to '*', indicating we have read 
     * the segment.
     */
    *shm = '*';

    exit(0);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [Distributed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize your data, put it in the shared memory, then de-serialize, just like you would if you sent data over a network. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-a-nsdata-into-an-hexadeximal-string) is a bit in-efficient in that it serialises to a text format, but it should work well enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16294825/193892 it may be better to use distributed objects though.