# Restore NSData from inside a text file back to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I am saving a NSDicitonary to a file using the following code:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:anOrder options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted  error:nil];
url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|%@|%@", aURL, anAction, aGUID, jsonData];
        [url  writeToFile:[self baseFilePath:aGUID]  atomically:NO encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```

Which give me my file on disk with contents:

```
https://www.myserver.com/orders/18/0FE40280-7C83-486F-AB75-FD9E359F4823|save|0FE40280-7C83-486F-AB75-FD9E359F4823|<7b0a2020 22437573 746f6d65 724e616d 6522203a 2022342e 302e3120 54657374 222c0a20 20224f72 64657249 74656d73 22203a20 5b0a2020 20207b0a 20202020 20202275 64663130 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 20202253 6f72744f 72646572 22203a20 302c0a20 20202020 20227564 66313422 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20224361 7465676f 72792220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 2244696d 656e7369 6f6e7322 203a2022 32345c22 7833345c 22222c0a 20202020 2020224f 72646572 4974656d 49442220 3a20302c 0a202020 20202022 75646631 3822203a 20225069 6e6b222c 0a202020 20202022 4f726465 72475549 4422203a 20223046 45343032 38302d37 4338332d 34383646 2d414237 352d4644 39453335 39463438 3233222c 0a202020 20202022 43617461 6c6f674e 616d6522 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20225544 46332220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 226f7264 65724d75 6c746970 6c655175 616e7469 74792220 3a20312c 0a202020 20202022 4974656d 54797065 22203a20 6e756c6c 2c0a2020 20202020 2253616c 65735265 70494422 203a2030 2c0a2020 20202020 22486173 4c696e65 4974656d 44697363 6f756e74 22203a20 302c0a20 20202020 20224261 73655072 69636522 203a2030 2c0a2020 20202020 22506965 63657342 6f782220 3a20302c 0a202020 20202022 4974656d 49442220 3a202254 462d3031 3039222c 0a202020 20202022 61646469 74696f6e 616c5068 6f746f73 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 20202277 65696768 7422203a 20302c0a 20202020 20202255 44463422 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20227564 66313122 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20224469 73636f75 6e745363 6f706522 203a206e 756c6c2c 0a202020 20202022 44657363 72697074 696f6e22 203a2022 74657374 3330222c 0a202020 20202022 44697363 6f756e74 49735174 79426173 65642220 3a206e75 6c6c2c0a 20202020 20202250 686f746f 4e616d65 22203a20 2274662d 30313039 222c0a20 20202020 2022536f 75726365 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 20202243 7573746f 6d65724e 756d6265 7222203a 206e756c 6c2c0a20 20202020 20227564 66313522 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20224469 73636f6e 74696e75 65642220 3a20302c 0a202020 20202022 4d6f6469 66696572 4c697374 49442220 3a20302c 0a202020 20202022 50726963 6522203a 20313235 2c0a2020 20202020 22726570 6f727443 61746567 6f727922 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20227564 66313922 203a2022 32345c22 7833345c 22222c0a 20202020 20202275 64663622 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20225072 6f647563 74494422 203a2030 2c0a2020 20202020 22554446 3522203a 20223330 222c0a20 20202020 20224375 62657322 203a2030 2c0a2020 20202020 22506172 656e7449 74656d49 4422203a 206e756c 6c2c0a20 20202020 2022436f 6d706c65 74654974 656d4944 22203a20 2254462d 30313039 222c0a20 20202020 20227564 66372220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 22756466 31322220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 22457870 6f727465 6422203a 206e756c 6c2c0a20 20202020 20224469 73636f75 6e745479 70652220 3a206e75 6c6c2c0a 20202020 2020224e 6f746573 22203a20 6e756c6c 2c0a2020 20202020 22756466 31362220 3a202241 72636869 74656374 7572616c 222c0a20 20202020 20227564 66382220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 22486173 4d6f6469 66696572 7322203a 206e756c 6c2c0a20 20202020 20225174 7922203a 20312c0a 20202020 20202241 64646974 696f6e61 6c496d61 6765436f 756e7422 203a2030 2c0a2020 20202020 22436174 616c6f67 436f6465 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 2020224d 616e7566 61637475 72657249 4422203a 2031382c 0a202020 20202022 55504322 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 2022556e 69744f66 4d656173 75726522 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20227564 66392220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 22497465 6d4e616d 6522203a 20224152 43484954 45435455 52414c20 44455441 494c222c 0a202020 20202022 75646631 3322203a 2022222c 0a202020 20202022 75646632 3022203a 2022222c 0a202020 20202022 6f726465 72497465 6d475549 4422203a 20223942 44344643 30302d33 4635412d 34453636 2d423333 342d4136 38354146 43433546 4233222c 0a202020 20202022 75646631 3722203a 20225061 696e7469 6e67222c 0a202020 20202022 55444631 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 20202244 6973636f 756e7456 616c7565 22203a20 302c0a20 20202020 20224973 44656c65 74656422 203a206e 756c6c2c 0a202020 20202022 53756254 6f74616c 22203a20 3132352c 0a202020 20202022 4578706f 72744461 74652220 3a206e75 6c6c2c0a 20202020 2020224f 76657272 72696465 50726963 6522203a 20302c0a 20202020 2020224f 72646572 49442220 3a20302c 0a202020 20202022 55444632 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 2020226f 6e48616e 64517561 6e746974 7922203a 20323938 320a2020 20207d0a 20205d2c 0a202022 43757374 6f6d6572 4e756d62 65722220 3a202231 34363031 3731222c 0a202022 57726974 74656e46 6f725265 704e756d 62657222 203a2022 222c0a20 20224f72 64657254 6f74616c 22203a20 3132352c 0a202022 5265704e 756d6265 7222203a 2022222c 0a202022 53616c65 73526570 49442220 3a203233 352c0a20 20225772 69747465 6e42794e 616d6522 203a2022 4d617877 656c6c20 46726173 6572220a 7d>
```

I load the file when I need it an split it into the parts I have saved as above:

```
NSString *path =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@" ,documentsDirectory, [files objectAtIndex:i]];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *urlAction = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

The 4th part of the urlAction array contains my NSData: `[urlAction objectAtIndex:3]`

```
<7b0a2020 22437573 746f6d65 724e616d 6522203a 2022342e 302e3120 54657374 222c0a20 20224f72 64657249 74656d73 22203a20 5b0a2020 20207b0a 20202020 20202275 64663130 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 20202253 6f72744f 72646572 22203a20 302c0a20 20202020 20227564 66313422 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20224361 7465676f 72792220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 2244696d 656e7369 6f6e7322 203a2022 32345c22 7833345c 22222c0a 20202020 2020224f 72646572 4974656d 49442220 3a20302c 0a202020 20202022 75646631 3822203a 20225069 6e6b222c 0a202020 20202022 4f726465 72475549 4422203a 20223046 45343032 38302d37 4338332d 34383646 2d414237 352d4644 39453335 39463438 3233222c 0a202020 20202022 43617461 6c6f674e 616d6522 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20225544 46332220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 226f7264 65724d75 6c746970 6c655175 616e7469 74792220 3a20312c 0a202020 20202022 4974656d 54797065 22203a20 6e756c6c 2c0a2020 20202020 2253616c 65735265 70494422 203a2030 2c0a2020 20202020 22486173 4c696e65 4974656d 44697363 6f756e74 22203a20 302c0a20 20202020 20224261 73655072 69636522 203a2030 2c0a2020 20202020 22506965 63657342 6f782220 3a20302c 0a202020 20202022 4974656d 49442220 3a202254 462d3031 3039222c 0a202020 20202022 61646469 74696f6e 616c5068 6f746f73 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 20202277 65696768 7422203a 20302c0a 20202020 20202255 44463422 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20227564 66313122 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20224469 73636f75 6e745363 6f706522 203a206e 756c6c2c 0a202020 20202022 44657363 72697074 696f6e22 203a2022 74657374 3330222c 0a202020 20202022 44697363 6f756e74 49735174 79426173 65642220 3a206e75 6c6c2c0a 20202020 20202250 686f746f 4e616d65 22203a20 2274662d 30313039 222c0a20 20202020 2022536f 75726365 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 20202243 7573746f 6d65724e 756d6265 7222203a 206e756c 6c2c0a20 20202020 20227564 66313522 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20224469 73636f6e 74696e75 65642220 3a20302c 0a202020 20202022 4d6f6469 66696572 4c697374 49442220 3a20302c 0a202020 20202022 50726963 6522203a 20313235 2c0a2020 20202020 22726570 6f727443 61746567 6f727922 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20227564 66313922 203a2022 32345c22 7833345c 22222c0a 20202020 20202275 64663622 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20225072 6f647563 74494422 203a2030 2c0a2020 20202020 22554446 3522203a 20223330 222c0a20 20202020 20224375 62657322 203a2030 2c0a2020 20202020 22506172 656e7449 74656d49 4422203a 206e756c 6c2c0a20 20202020 2022436f 6d706c65 74654974 656d4944 22203a20 2254462d 30313039 222c0a20 20202020 20227564 66372220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 22756466 31322220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 22457870 6f727465 6422203a 206e756c 6c2c0a20 20202020 20224469 73636f75 6e745479 70652220 3a206e75 6c6c2c0a 20202020 2020224e 6f746573 22203a20 6e756c6c 2c0a2020 20202020 22756466 31362220 3a202241 72636869 74656374 7572616c 222c0a20 20202020 20227564 66382220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 22486173 4d6f6469 66696572 7322203a 206e756c 6c2c0a20 20202020 20225174 7922203a 20312c0a 20202020 20202241 64646974 696f6e61 6c496d61 6765436f 756e7422 203a2030 2c0a2020 20202020 22436174 616c6f67 436f6465 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 2020224d 616e7566 61637475 72657249 4422203a 2031382c 0a202020 20202022 55504322 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 2022556e 69744f66 4d656173 75726522 203a2022 222c0a20 20202020 20227564 66392220 3a202222 2c0a2020 20202020 22497465 6d4e616d 6522203a 20224152 43484954 45435455 52414c20 44455441 494c222c 0a202020 20202022 75646631 3322203a 2022222c 0a202020 20202022 75646632 3022203a 2022222c 0a202020 20202022 6f726465 72497465 6d475549 4422203a 20223942 44344643 30302d33 4635412d 34453636 2d423333 342d4136 38354146 43433546 4233222c 0a202020 20202022 75646631 3722203a 20225061 696e7469 6e67222c 0a202020 20202022 55444631 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 20202244 6973636f 756e7456 616c7565 22203a20 302c0a20 20202020 20224973 44656c65 74656422 203a206e 756c6c2c 0a202020 20202022 53756254 6f74616c 22203a20 3132352c 0a202020 20202022 4578706f 72744461 74652220 3a206e75 6c6c2c0a 20202020 2020224f 76657272 72696465 50726963 6522203a 20302c0a 20202020 2020224f 72646572 49442220 3a20302c 0a202020 20202022 55444632 22203a20 22222c0a 20202020 2020226f 6e48616e 64517561 6e746974 7922203a 20323938 320a2020 20207d0a 20205d2c 0a202022 43757374 6f6d6572 4e756d62 65722220 3a202231 34363031 3731222c 0a202022 57726974 74656e46 6f725265 704e756d 62657222 203a2022 222c0a20 20224f72 64657254 6f74616c 22203a20 3132352c 0a202022 5265704e 756d6265 7222203a 2022222c 0a202022 53616c65 73526570 49442220 3a203233 352c0a20 20225772 69747465 6e42794e 616d6522 203a2022 4d617877 656c6c20 46726173 6572220a 7d>
```

But I cannot for some reason get this to convert back to a NSDictionary for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a really bad idea to convert an `NSData` object to s string by calling the `description` method (which is what you do indirectly when create the URL via `stringWithFormat`.

You should convert the `NSData` to a string using a better approach. Either use a base-64 encoder or write your own code to create a string from the `NSData` that doesn't have spaces or any other possible extraneous output from the `description` method.

Once you do that then you can get back to how to handle `urlAction[3]` which will be the encode string representing the `NSData`. You will need to convert the string back to an `NSData` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your string `<7b0a2020 22736179 ...>` and convert it back into an NSData object using the below code:

```
NSString *dataStr = [urlAction objectAtIndex:3];
dataStr = [dataStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
dataStr = [dataStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:dataStr.length/2];
for (int i=0; i < dataStr.length; i+=2) {
    char byteStr[3] = {
        [dataStr characterAtIndex:i],
        [dataStr characterAtIndex:i+1], '\0'
    };
    unsigned char byteValue = (unsigned char)strtol(byteStr,NULL,16);
    [data appendBytes:&byteValue length:sizeof(byteValue)];
}
```

However, as @rmaddy points out I wouldn't rely on the `description` method of NSData (which is what's ultimately called when you pass an `NSData` to this [NSData category to convert to a hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-a-nsdata-into-an-hexadeximal-string) without the <, > or spaces.