# iOS APNS: sending the device token to the provider in string format

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, string-formatting, devicetoken

I need to send the APNS device token of my iOS app to my provider by calling a service that expects JSON data in my request. I'm reading Apple's [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2) and it only says that the `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` delegate method passes the device token as `NSData` and you should pass it to your provider encoded in binary data. But I need it to be converted to string in order to be able to send a JSON request to my provider.

I've also been reading several posts related to this, since it looks it is a common scenario, but I've found some different ways to convert such device token to string to send it, and I'm not sure which of them should be the most appropriate. Which would the most reliable way to deal with this be? I suppose my provider will need to convert this string back to call APNS, and I also need to store this token in the app in order to safely compare it with the new value if a new token is generated and `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` is called, to send the token only if it has changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right that you have to convert the device token from `NSData` to `NSString` to
be able to send it with a JSON object. But what conversion method you choose is completely
up to you or the requirements of the provider. The most common methods are a
hex string (see for example [Best way to serialize an NSData into a hexadeximal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-a-nsdata-into-an-hexadeximal-string)) or a Base64 string (using 
`base64EncodedStringWithOptions`). Both are 100% "reliable".

Also you should always send the device token to the provider and not only when it has changed. The provider has to keep a database of all device tokens with a timestamp of 
when it was sent last recently, in order to compare the timestamp with a possible response
from the "feedback service".

Comment: Thanks, I finally used the code you indicated to create a hexadecimal string

Answer (score 8):

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

After doing above lines of code ,add the method below

```
#pragma mark Push Notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
NSString  *token_string = [[[[deviceToken description]    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
NSString* strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.sample.com?device_token=%@&type=IOS",token_string];
strURL=[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",strURL);
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSLog(@"content---%@", fileData);
}
```

After the above listed steps you can use this delegate function to retrieve and handle push notification once it comes.The below added method will fire either the app is running in background or not.The method given below is available from ios7.0

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

Comment: This is my understanding to implement pushnotification,if you find any mistakes with this code please feel free to addd.....

Comment: Had similar problem, the solution was to follow your answer which was to remove all "space" characters from the device token. This was for PushSharp not sure if this is a general guideline for the Push Notification API.

Answer (score 6):

```
const unsigned *tokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
NSString *hexToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                      ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
                      ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
                      ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])];
```

Converting data to bytes means we can count it. Removing spaces and <> is really not a good idea

Comment: Makes a lot more sense than the other future error prone "description" approaches! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)_deviceToken {

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_deviceToken];
//replace '<' and '>' along with spaces before you send it to the server.
}
```

this has worked reliably for me on almost all web platforms.