# What is the Kotlin equivalent of CC_SHA256 from Swift?

Tags: android, swift, encryption, kotlin, sha256

I have the following code in Swift:

```
static func sha256(_ data: Data) -> Data? 
{
   guard let res = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)) else { return nil }
   CC_SHA256((data as NSData).bytes, CC_LONG(data.count), res.mutableBytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))
   return res as Data
}
```

I'm unsure how to translate `CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH` and `CC_SHA256` when doing Android development in Kotlin.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Did you see the Java? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26361457/1820553

Comment: No I didn't see that. Thank you.

Comment: It's just binary SHA-256 without any encoding / decoding. What's there to see? Oh, and a guard statement in case the system isn't able to allocate 32 mutable bites (sigh).

Comment: Ah, such a helpful comment.

Comment: Well, you can lookup how to perform *just* SHA-256 in Java or Kotlin, right? Create algorithm, feed data, get output. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

A more generic approach (as suggested by user2340612):

```
private fun hashString(input: String, algorithm: String): String    {
    return MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm)
        .digest(input.toByteArray())
        .fold("", { str, it -> str + "%02x".format(it) })
}
```

[List of valid algorithms](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/security/MessageDigest)

Kudos to [this guy](https://gist.github.com/lovubuntu/164b6b9021f5ba54cefc67f60f7a1a25#gistcomment-3123763).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish what I needed with this:

```
import android.util.Base64
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

fun calculateSH256(secret: String): String {
   val sha256hex = Hashing.sha256()
       .hashString(secret, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
       .asBytes()

   return Base64.encodeToString(sha256hex, Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

and this in the Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-android'
}
```

Comment: Could you add some test cases, too?

Comment: @EthanAllen if you don't want to import a whole new library just for SHA-256 you can have a look at the built-in [MessageDigest](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/security/MessageDigest) class. You can get an instance with `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")` and then call `digest` with your input (if short, otherwise consider chunking the input and feeding the digest via `update`)