# Hex to Decimal - Swift

Tags: swift, hex

Sorry if this seems really simple, I just can't find it anywhere online.

I have a UInt8 in hex, I need to get it to a decimal. How do I achieve this in swift?

For example:

"ff"

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert hex number to bin in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284223/how-to-convert-hex-number-to-bin-in-swift)

Comment: (if by "decimal" you mean a true `UInt8` like `255`, and not another string with decimal representation, `"255"`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45667905/3908884

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you have a string representation, `"ff"`, you can use [`UInt8(_:radix:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint8/2925881-init):

```
let string = "ff"
if let value = UInt8(string, radix: 16) {
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: That last one works, except for one thing. All Ints are correct except 0. It returns nil instead of 0 and thne jumps to 1. Ideas?

Comment: I fixed it. Issue was var value: UInt8!. I made it var value: UInt8 = 0. Now it works.

Comment: Good catch. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I've simplified my answer, excising `strtoul` from the answer.

Comment: I have FFFF hex string , total 16 bits so I used UInt16, thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 5):

you can use the function strtoul to convert your hex to decimal:

```
let result = UInt8(strtoul("ff", nil, 16))  // 255
```

Comment: That works. One more thing. If I print my NSData it's <ff>. I can convert to string and remove the first and last character. But is that the best way to do it?

Comment: @JoeBayLD You do _not_ to get the string representation and then convert that to binary. Use `getBytes` to get the binary data directly.

Comment: Thanks @Rob I just found this and appears to be working. I'll post a new question of the final product to make sure it's most efficient. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424831/cant-covert-nsdata-to-nsstring-swift

Answer (score 5):

Try this code, It's work for me.

// Hex to decimal

```
let h2 = "ff"
let d4 = Int(h2, radix: 16)!
print(d4)
```

Hope this is help for some one

Answer (score 4):

If your HEX value is not a String, but just something you want to convert compile-time, you can also use:

```
let integer : UInt8 = 0xff
```

So prefixing it with `0x` will do the job.