# Need help converting this PHP sha256 hashing code to swift (iOS)

Tags: php, ios, swift, hash, sha256

I need to convert this pice of PHP code to swift to create hashes, I am using a hash pattern in PHP to hash 2 strings with SHA256 and I would like to do this in swift, any ideas?
The SELF::SECRET is a secret key, and the SELF::HASH_PATTERN is my pattern and looks something like this: "00101010011100001010"

```
public function hash($first, $second) {
    // Append the secret to the values.
    $first = self::SECRET . $first;
    $second = $second . self::SECRET;

    // Hash the values.
    $hash = hash_init('sha256');
    hash_update($hash, $first);
    $hash1 = hash_final($hash);
    $hash = hash_init('sha256');
    hash_update($hash, $second);
    $hash2 = hash_final($hash);

    // Create a new hash with pieces of the two we just made.
    $result = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen(self::HASH_PATTERN); $i++) {
        $result .= substr(self::HASH_PATTERN, $i, 1) ? $hash2[$i] : $hash1[$i];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:
    This is the part which I can't figure out:

```
    $hash = hash_init('sha256');
    hash_update($hash, $first);
    $hash1 = hash_final($hash);
```

UPDATE:

After a few hours of doing research and coding I finally got it figured out.
This is the code that I wrote, maybe not the best, but it works :)
I used a small class from github for generating SHA256 strings in swift called NSHash

```
func create_token(first:String, second:String) -> String {

    var newFirst = constants.secret + first as NSString
    var newSecond = second + constants.secret as NSString

    var hash1 = newFirst.SHA256()
    var hash2 = newSecond.SHA256()

    var result = ""

    for var i = 0; i < countElements(constants.hash_pattern); i++ {

        var character = "\(constants.hash_pattern[i])" as String
        var number:Int = character.toInt()!

        if number == 1 {

            result = "\(result)\(hash2[i])"


        }else {
            result = "\(result)\(hash1[i])"

        }

     }

    return result
}
```

Comment: There are some "SHA-256 in Swift" answers already, so perhaps you can show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Otherwise it would look like a *"Translate this code for me!"* question :)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424831/cant-covert-nsdata-to-nsstring-swift.