# md5 hash returns with encapsulation in swift

Tags: swift, md5

I have used this [md5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964291/how-to-get-md5-hash-from-string-in-swift-and-make-bridge-header) and I get the hashed result.  However, the return is like this: `<8f833933 03a151ea 33bf6e3e bbc28594>`.  Am new to swift so am not entirely sure whether it's an encapsulation.  How do I get rid of the less and greater than sign?

Comment: That means that the NSData object is printed using its `description` method. If you search for "NSData to hex string" then you should find some solutions (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29642198/1187415).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the signature, the function returns a NSData object:

```
func md5(#string: String) -> NSData
```

If you want to convert it to a string, you’ll need to encode it in a human-readable format. The most common is a hexadecimal representation.

If you use the newer Swift 2 function from that question, which returns a UInt8 array

```
func md5(string string: String) -> [UInt8] {
    var digest = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    if let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        CC_MD5(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
    }

    return digest
}
```

you could use this handy `toHex` function:

```
func toHex(bytes: [UInt8]) -> String {
    var numbers = [String]()
    for byte in bytes {
        if byte < 0x10 {
            numbers.append("0")
        }
        numbers.append(String(byte, radix: 16, uppercase: true))
    }
    return numbers.joinWithSeparator("")
}
```

Then this returns a string:

```
toHex(md5("Hello"))
```

(In my opinion you should always prefer pure Swift types (array of UInt8) over Foundation types (NSData).)

Comment: @user3813647 If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.