# byteArray to Hex NSString - adds some wrong hex content

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, hex

I am trying to convert the byteArray to a Hex NSString.

Here is the solution that I referred to convert it into hex NSString. But, I discovered It add's **ffffffffffffff**. How can I get correct hex NSString?

[Best way to serialize an NSData into a hexadeximal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-a-nsdata-into-an-hexadeximal-string)

```
const char myByteArray[] = {
        0x12,0x23,0x34,0x45,0x56,0x67,0x78,0x89,
        0x12,0x23,0x34,0x45,
        0x56,0x67,0x78,0x89 };

    NSData *myByteData=[NSData dataWithBytes:myByteArray length:sizeof(myByteArray)];
    NSMutableString *myHexString= [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:myByteData.length*2];
    for(int i=0;i<myByteData.length;i++){
        ;
        NSString *resultString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02lx",(unsigned long)myByteArray[i]];
        [myHexString appendString:resultString];
    }
```

The output String

```
12233445566778ffffffffffffff8912233445566778ffffffffffffff89
```

Comment: What is the NSData for? You never use it so why did you create it?

Comment: In the link that I had mentioned NSData was used to get length. So, I had added, but actually there is no need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial byte data is `char` rather than `unsigned char`.  This means that any values >127 (0x7f) will be seen as a twos-complement negative number, giving `ffffffffffffff89`.

If you change your data to be `unsigned char` you will get the desired result.

```
const unsigned char myByteArray[] = {
        0x12,0x23,0x34,0x45,0x56,0x67,0x78,0x89,
        0x12,0x23,0x34,0x45,
        0x56,0x67,0x78,0x89 };

NSData *myByteData=[NSData dataWithBytes:myByteArray length:sizeof(myByteArray)];
NSMutableString *myHexString= [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:myByteData.length*2];
for(int i=0;i<myByteData.length;i++){

    NSString *resultString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02lx",(unsigned long)myByteArray[i]];
    [myHexString appendString:resultString];

}
```

Comment: If i use const unsigned char, then the for loop condition should be [myHexString appendFormat:@"%02x",myByteArray[i]], this will avoid conversion to unsigned long.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why you were converting to a long.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `unsigned long` for each of your bytes. And what's the point of `myByteData` if you don't use it?

And since you are not really using `char`, use `uint8_t`.

Try this:

```
const uint8_t myByteArray[] = {
    0x12,0x23,0x34,0x45,0x56,0x67,0x78,0x89,
    0x12,0x23,0x34,0x45,
    0x56,0x67,0x78,0x89 };

size_t len = sizeof(myByteArray) / sizeof(uint8_t);
NSMutableString *myHexString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len * 2];
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    [myHexString appendFormat:@"%02x", (int)myByteArray[i]];
}
```

Comment: Can the length be obtained from size_t len = sizeof(myByteArray)?

Comment: `sizeof(myByteArray)` is the number of bytes. Dividing by the size of each element of the array gives the length. In this case it's the same since each element is one byte.

Comment: yes uint8_t is unsigned char. That would be shorthand notation.

Comment: It's more than shorthand. It's more clear. You have a set of unsigned 8-bit integer values. `uint8_t` better expresses that use than does `unsigned char`.