# Wrong charset of file names after unzip

Tags: swift, zip, ssziparchive

I have the following problem: I extracted a zip file via SSZipArchive (in a Swift app) and there are some file names with "invalid" characters.
I think the reason is that I zipped the files under Windows and so the names are now coded in ANSI.

Is there a way to convert all the "corrupted" folder and file names during the unzip process?
Or later? It would be no problem if I have to iterate over the folder tree and rename the files.
But I have no idea how to find out which names are set in ANSI and I also don't know how to correct the charset.

Comment: please provide a sample zip and report it on github tracker

Answer (score 1):

The [official spec](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) says that the path should be either encoded in Code Page 437 MS-DOS Latin US or UTF-8 (if Bit 11 of the general purpose field is set):

> D.1 The ZIP format has historically supported only the original IBM PC
>   character  encoding set, commonly referred to as IBM Code Page 437. 
>   This limits storing  file name characters to only those within the
>   original MS-DOS range of values  and does not properly support file
>   names in other character encodings, or  languages. To address this
>   limitation, this specification will support the  following change.
>
> D.2 If general purpose bit 11 is unset, the file name and comment
>   should conform  to the original ZIP character encoding.  If general
>   purpose bit 11 is set, the  filename and comment must support The
>   Unicode Standard, Version 4.1.0 or  greater using the character
>   encoding form defined by the UTF-8 storage  specification.  The
>   Unicode Standard is published by the The Unicode Consortium
>   (www.unicode.org).  UTF-8 encoded data stored within ZIP files  is
>   expected to not include a byte order mark (BOM).

I recently released a Swift open source implementation of the ZIP file format called [ZIPFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation). It conforms to the standard and should be able to detect Windows path names and decode them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably fixed in latest SSZipArchive (currently 2.1.1). I've implemented support for non-Unicode filenames in a way similar to the code below, so you can reuse it to process your filenames yourself if you want.

OK, it's in Objective-C, but as SSZipArchive has the fix in itself already, you shouldn't need it anymore. Otherwise, either make a bridging header to include the objective-c code to your swift app, or convert it to Swift (should be easy).

```
@implementation NSString (SSZipArchive)

+ (NSString *)filenameStringWithCString:(const char *)filename size:(uint16_t)size_filename
{
    // unicode conversion attempt
    NSString *strPath = @(filename);
    if (strPath) {
        return strPath;
    }

    // if filename is non-unicode, detect and transform Encoding
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)filename length:sizeof(unsigned char) * size_filename];
    // supported encodings are in [NSString availableStringEncodings]
    [NSString stringEncodingForData:data encodingOptions:nil convertedString:&strPath usedLossyConversion:nil];
    if (strPath) {
        return strPath;
    }

    // if filename encoding is non-detected, we default to something based on data
    // note: hexString is more readable than base64RFC4648 for debugging unknown encodings
    strPath = [data hexString];
    return strPath;
}
@end

@implementation NSData (SSZipArchive)

// initWithBytesNoCopy from NSProgrammer, Jan 25 '12: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9009321/1033581
// hexChars from Peter, Aug 19 '14: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25378464/1033581
// not implemented as too lengthy: a potential mapping improvement from Moose, Nov 3 '15: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33501154/1033581
- (NSString *)hexString
{
    const char *hexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    NSUInteger length = self.length;
    const unsigned char *bytes = self.bytes;
    char *chars = malloc(length * 2);
    // TODO: check for NULL
    char *s = chars;
    NSUInteger i = length;
    while (i--) {
        *s++ = hexChars[*bytes >> 4];
        *s++ = hexChars[*bytes & 0xF];
        bytes++;
    }
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:chars
                                                   length:length * 2
                                                 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                             freeWhenDone:YES];
    return str;
}
@end
```