# NSDATA description returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, xcode11, ios13

`NSData` description returning nil and making the `NSData` object nil. My code has stopped working and I would like to get this working again.

If I compile my code in `Xcode` 10 it will get the `NSData` description fine. But if I use `Xcode` 11 it will give me nil as the description and it will make the `NSData` nil as well. I'm confused as to how this is happening. Is this because it's still a beta release? Is this kind of thing normal in beta releases? I just want to make sure my code still works before the new iOS 13 an iPAD OS 13 come out.

`NSString *result = [[data description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];`

Comment: You shouldn’t be using `description`, you should convert the data to a string properly.

Comment: It's not recommended to use `description`, not at all. Apple could decide to change the output, and tomorrow it might print `<NSData: pointerAddress> <hexData>` and break your code. Instead look how to convert NSData to Hex String: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-an-nsdata-into-a-hexadeximal-string etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to serialize an NSData into a hexadeximal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-an-nsdata-into-a-hexadeximal-string)

Comment: I highly doubt that calling `[data description]` is causing your `NSData` object to be nil. I'd look more into where you're getting that `NSData` from and set a break point immediately after you're `NSData` object gets created to ensure that it actually exists and if it doesn't look into why the object is being set to nil.

Answer (score 1):

See https://twitter.com/steipete/status/1174111017900503040 - iOS 13 behavior (written at time of GM seed 2).

As others have said, you should not be using [NSData description] this way.