# Using encryption in save data to avoid cheating in an iPhone game

Tags: iphone, encryption, app-store, appstore-approval

I've read the Apple export restrictions for app using encryption and I'm baffled.

Is it worth to do all the CCATS / SNAP-R procedure only for encrypting my gamesave data?

Using encryption will prevent my app to be sold in some region?

Can my app be rejected because of encryption?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is not worth using encryption. A simple checksum can do pretty much the same.
Instead of encrypting your savegames you could calculate a checksum to detect if someone tried to change the savegame.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @pre, skip the encryption part and use [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) ([on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735714/iphone-and-hmac-sha-1-encoding)) to make sure that your saves were not altered. To protected the HMAC secrete I would generate it using any random generator and store it in the keychain.

Keychain entries are not backed up so it is hard to read them if your iphone is not jailbroken. You can try this wrapper around keychain: https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController

Answer (score 1):

The registration process is not that difficult. Most of it is filling out company info (name,address, etc.). There is only one part that asks you about your encryption. The process takes about 3 days and a few back-and-fourths.

Apple has the checkbox in iTunesConnect to mark if you use encryption for anything other than sign-in credentials. It appears like they are just covering their butts. You submit a screenshot of your completed form and they sign off on it right away.

For an outline of the steps you need to take see:
https://www.chatmap.io/blog/iPhone-iTunes-ERN-Encryption.php

In short, it's not a great deal of work to register.